# Error message relating to variance

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When attempt to type the result of sortBy to RDD :

```
  val counts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = file.flatMap(line => line.split(" "))
    .map(word => (word.trim.toLowerCase, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)   
val sorted : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any] = counts.sortBy(-_._2)
```

receive compiler error :

```
type mismatch;  found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]  required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Any] Note: (String, Int) <: Any, but class RDD is invariant in type T. You may wish to define T as +T instead. (SLS 4.5) Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
```

What is the meaning of  `class RDD is invariant in type T` ?

If use instead :

```
   val sorted : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[_] = counts.sortBy(-_._2)
```

Then why is compilation successful ?

Comment: I guess if you use a wildcard, you still leave it to the compiler to figure out the type. If you specify `RDD[Any]`, then you require conversion from `RDD[(String,Int)]` to `RDD[Any]` which is not allowed (that's what "invariant in type" means).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RDD is invariant. So, even if `(String, Int)` is a subclass of `Any`, RDD[(String, Int)] is not a subclass of RDD[Any]. So you cannot assign it to a `RDD[Any]`.

`RDD[_]` means I don't care about what's T in `RDD[T]`.

Because `variance` is a big topic in Scala, I cannot give you the whole picture. Here is only a simple introduction about it:

If a type C is covariant (C[+T] in Scala), it means if A is a subclass of B, C[A] is a subclass of C[B].

If a type C is contravariant (C[-T] in Scala), it means if A is a subclass of B, C[B] is a subclass of C[A].

If a type C is invariant (C[T] in Scala), there is no subclass relation between C[A] and C[B] if A != B.

If you want to learn more about variance and `_`, I recommend [Scala in Depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182706).

Comment: thanks, I also found this helpful  :http://skipoleschris.blogspot.com/2011/06/invariance-covariance-and.html "This is an example of an invariant type. Even though the parameterised type is a subclass of the more general one, we can't assign it to an instance that has been parameterised with the more general type. This is the standard generics model of Scala and is also the way that the Java language handles generics."